# getattribute() in osl is not working

Tags: scripting, uv, shaders, osl

I'm trying to get the UV coordinates of from UVMap using `getattribute()` as follows :

```
#include "stdosl.h"

shader node_uv_map(
    string name = "",
    output point UV = point(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
)
{
    if (name == "")
        getattribute("geom:uv", UV);
    else
        getattribute(name, UV);
}
```

with the `name` empty or containing the UVmap name there is no output

- how to perform that correctly
- is there another way to get the uvmap coordinates in osl
- what are othor attribute that can be retrieved using `getattribute` beside [these](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/OSL#Attributes)

Blender 2.7b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The texture only appeared after I added another Image Texture node (which is not realated to anything). Muting this node if enough to make the texture disappear.

The topic is also discussed on an older [BA-Thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?270332-OSL-Goodness/page11)

You could use Input/UV-Map node to get the UV-coordinates:

Wiring the UV makes them accessible for getattributes

[image]

Comment: thanks that worked for me, this gives the active UVMap only so how can i choose another one through osl

Comment: @Chebhou you can have as many as you want by adding multiple UVMap -Nodes with different UV-Maps. (if I get you right)

Comment: i meant accessing them with their names getattribute("UVMap.001",UV)

Comment: @Chebhou added another example

Comment: I haven't used getattribute much, I'm thinking for this it would easier and cleaner to have multiple vector inputs and connect a uvmap node to the script node.

Comment: @sambler the problem with getattribute() extends to all other attributes not only UVmap for instance [Getting a Light vector in OSL](http://www.swineworld.org/2012/11/getting-light-vector-in-osl-for-blender.html)